Determining the p-value of a test statistic, which is not distributed according to a commonly known distribution under the null hypothesis
Currently I am working in R on a project that aims to identify Dragon King events (massive outliers) in large datasets. These outliers appear for example in the city sizes in England, where London is the outlier.
The problem I have encountered is that I am using the test statistics described in the paper "Multiple Outlier Detection in Samples with Exponential & Pareto Tails: Redeeming the Inward Approach & Detecting Dragon Kings" by Spencer Wheatly and Didier Sornette. The problem specifically is that these test statistics do not follow the usual distributions under the null hypothesis (no outliers present in the dataset). The reference mentioned above does refer to other papers, which should seemingly clarify the distribution function but these don't seem to be very applicable as they are either very outdated, or don't discuss the test statistic from the original reference.
What I have done now is performed simulations, where I have run many different cases of the null hypothesis and used the test statistic on it and then computed the distribution function empirically using the ecdf function in R. This gives me, what I have to believe to be, a reliable empirical distribution function. Unfortunately the p-values that I compute don't seem plausible. This is in the sense that when I compute the p-values for samples that clearly contain outliers, the p-value is not significant enough to reject the null. Thus I assume I must be misunderstanding something or doing something wrong.
I had expected to be able to replicate the graphs found in the original reference (on page 10 for example) but have thus far been unable to do this.

At any rate, I wonder what you could conclude if London or another city doesn't fit into the distribution derived from a particular theory of city formation, except that there is some other mechanism in play. But maybe that is the whole point, to identify a gap in an existing theory with the aim of looking for ways to fill it.

I should specify that my example is not looking at city sizes, as indeed those are a finite sample dataset - but instead I am looking at disturbance data in forests. I am looking to identify outliers (extreme events) in these datasets to be able to finally improve forest models. Hopefully that makes more sense! @RobertDodier
